# mysql | Codeigniter Active Records are adding extra back ticks to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

When i try to run query in through codeigniter active records i get error as it is adding extra ``` `` ```

This is the query the codeigniter is trying to execute

```
SELECT `T`.`id` AS TimeSheetID, DATE_FORMAT(T.date_created, `'%M')` AS MonthName FROM (`timesheet` T)
```

but this is the query that i actually want to execute.

```
SELECT `T`.`id` AS TimeSheetID, DATE_FORMAT(T.date_created, '%M') AS MonthName FROM (`timesheet` T)
```

how can i escape the extra colons added by the active records..

how can i write this statement to get the query work properly.

```
$this->db->select("
                T.id AS TimeSheetID,
                DATE_FORMAT(T.date_created,'%M') AS MonthName");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a second parameter `FALSE` in your `SELECT()`

So,

```
$this->db->select("
                T.id AS TimeSheetID,
                DATE_FORMAT(T.date_created,'%M') AS MonthName", FALSE);
```

**$this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.**

[Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: Thankyou sir, but it didnt worked for group_by i mean if i use this in group by i get error there also. and false didnt worked as second param?

Comment: Please read the documentation, parameter number is different for each function.

Comment: yes. just found out.. i can use the synonym name also in group_by.. i mean i used AS in select so then in group i used the nick of that select and it worked. Thanks again.