# Laravel 5.1 - DB is adding back ticks to my query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This function in a model I have:

```
public static function getUserQuestions($id_user = null, $sort_by = 'date')
{
    $getData = DB::table('questions')
        ->select('map_user_question_vote.id_question, questions.id, SUM(map_user_question_vote.vote) as votes', false)
        ->leftJoin('map_user_question_vote', 'map_user_question_vote.id_question', '=', 'questions.id')
        ->where('questions.id_user', $id_user)
        ->where('map_user_question_vote.id_question', 'questions.id')
        ->groupBy('questions.id')
        ->get();
}
```

is outputting this:

```
select `map_user_question_vote`.`id_question,` as `SUM(map_user_question_vote.vote)`, `` from `questions`
left join `map_user_question_vote` on `map_user_question_vote`.`id_question` = `questions`.`id`
where `questions`.`id_user` = 1 and `map_user_question_vote`.`id_question` = questions.id
group by `questions`.`id`
```

Same as this question:
[mysql | Codeigniter Active Records are adding extra back ticks to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480838/mysql-codeigniter-active-records-are-adding-extra-back-ticks-to-query)

But for Laravel, not CI.

You'll also notice that my SUM() as... is all messed up?
Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$getData = DB::table('questions')
->select(DB::raw('map_user_question_vote.id_question, questions.id, SUM(map_user_question_vote.vote) as votes'))
->leftJoin('map_user_question_vote', 'map_user_question_vote.id_question', '=', 'questions.id')
->where('questions.id_user', $id_user)
->where('map_user_question_vote.id_question', 'questions.id')
->groupBy('questions.id')
->get();
```

Comment: DB::raw.... How am I suppsed to learn stuff like that other that you good folk? I'm off to test now....

Comment: That fixed my backtick issue.. but now my Where statements are showing ? instead of the second argument:   where `questions`.`id_user` = ? and `map_user_question_vote`.`id_question` = ? --- additional: I am using ->toSql() instead of ->get() to view my SQL

Comment: Hmm... You might try looking for more examples in the Laravel docs (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries).

Comment: Yeah, on that now.. this bit: "For convenience, if you simply want to verify that a column is equal to a given value, you may pass the value directly as the second argument to the where method:" states that my code for ->where() is good.. no indication where ? is being generated... Hmmm

Comment: Awesome username btw...!

Comment: Oh @BakerStreet   it was ->whereRaw() I needed!!! (cheers for the nudge).. WHY ->where() doesn't work is still frustrating :p

Comment: I have the similar issue, it shows the backtick error for "FROM `users u`". Is there way to remove  backtick completely from the query?